# Evaluate $\lim s_n$ if $a_1=1$, $a_{n+1}=\frac1{s_n}-\sqrt2$, $s_n=a_1+\cdots+a_n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, limits

Let, $\{a_n\}$ be a sequence be defined by $a_1=1$ and $\displaystyle a_{n+1}=\frac{1}{a_1+a_2+\cdots +a_n}-\sqrt 2$ , for $n\ge 2$. Then find the sum of the series $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$.

To find the required sum we have to find out the limit of $\{a_n\}$. But I couldn't find any recurrence relation which helps.

Can you give any idea or some hint?

Comment: `To find the required sum we have to find out the limit of a_n` It's enough to prove that the series converges. Then the recurrence can be written in terms of the partial sums as $\,s_{n+1}-s_n=1 / s_n - \sqrt{2}\,$, which gives the limit (once determined that it exists).

Comment: Indeed, if the series converges at all then it must be true that $a_n\to0$.

Comment: @GregMartin Yes..but  how it helps?

Comment: @dxiv Yes..If the series converges then the sum will be $1/\sqrt 2$. Now how I can show that the series is convergent ?

Comment: Given $a_1=1$. Then $a_2=-0.414$ , $a_3=0.2928$, $a_4=-1.2930$......So the sequence is oscillatory...So $a_n$ can not be converge.And so the series is divergent..Is it? I think it is correct..Please check

Comment: @S717717 For the given $s_1=1$ the sequence of partial sums $s_{n+1}=s_n+1/s_n - \sqrt{2}$ is bounded within $[2 - \sqrt{2},1]\,$, and the odd/even subsequences are monotonic. The latter likely has some shortcut proof, though I don't see it offhand.

Comment: For every $n\geqslant1$, $$s_n=\frac1{a_{n+1}+\sqrt2}$$ hence $$a_{n+2}=\frac1{s_{n+1}}-\sqrt2=\frac1{s_n+a_{n+1}}-\sqrt2=\frac1{\frac1{a_{n+1}+\sqrt2}+a_{n+1}}-\sqrt2=g(a_{n+1})$$ with $$g(a)=-\frac{a(1+\sqrt2 a)}{1+\sqrt2 a+a^2}$$ Now, $g(0)=0$ and, for every $|a|\leqslant1$, $a\ne0$, $$|g(a)|<|a|$$ hence, either $a_k=0$ for some $k$, and then $s_n=\frac1{\sqrt2}$ for every $n\geqslant k-1$, or $(|a_n|)$ is decreasing to $0$. In both cases, $$\lim s_n=\frac1{\sqrt2}$$

Comment: @@Did) How $|a_n|$ decreasing to $0$ ? I got $|a_1|=1$ , |a_2|=0.414$ ,$|a_3|=0.2928$ , $|a_4|=1.2930$. So it is neither increasing nor decreasing.

Comment: Two things: using @@ instead of @ inactivates the signalization of your comment to me; your numerical computations are wrong (and I must say that the fact that you did not even check them when you received a *proof* that they are decreasing in absolute value is something difficult to understand).